# Node ssh2 sends multiple data events for a simple ls command

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, npm

I am trying to do a simple 'ls' using node ssh connection on localhost. The code is like this,

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');
var conn = new Connection();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  conn.shell('uptime', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    });
    stream.end('ls');
  });
}).connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 22,
  username: '*****',
  password: '*****'
});
```

And i am getting multiple data events, with the output like this,

```
STDOUT: Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)
* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
STDOUT: 
Last login: Sun Dec 28 09:28:21 2014 from localhost
STDOUT: ls
STDOUT: sk@sk-box:~$ l
STDOUT: s
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Append newline character after `ls` command.

```
var Connection = require('ssh2');
var conn = new Connection();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  conn.shell('uptime', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    });
    stream.end('ls\n');
  });
}).connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 22,
  username: '*****',
  password: '*****'
});
```